# react useEffect hook triggers only once although update redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

SImple hook component below, when submitting form it throws exception and useEffect hook triggers and prompts error message fine,

if submit again for some reason useEffect not triggers..

I can assure you submit, action works as expected since I follow up steps with debuggers..
it doesn't step into useEffect after first submit..

component:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const { messages, error } = useSelector((state) => state.contact)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    debugger
    if (error) {
      alert(messages)
    }
  }, [error, messages])

  const onSubmitForm = (data) => {
    dispatch(postContact(data))
  }
```

action:

```
export const postContact = ({ name, email, website, message }) => async (
  dispatch
) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: CONTACT_POST,
    })
    const response = await axios.post('/contact', {
      data: {
        Name: name,
        Email: email,
        Website: website,
        Message: message,
      },
    })
    dispatch({
      type: CONTACT_POST_SUCCESS,
      payload: response.data,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    debugger
    dispatch({
      type: CONTACT_POST_FAIL,
      error: error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

reducer:

```
export default function contact(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONTACT_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
      }
    case CONTACT_POST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: 'Completed successfully',
        error:false,
      }
    case CONTACT_POST_FAIL:
      debugger
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: action.error,
        error: true,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no value change for error & message property. Error value is always assigning as "true".  Try listening the entire state itself.

```
const contactState = useSelector((state) => state.contact)

 useEffect(() => {
    debugger
    if (error) {
      alert(messages)
    }
  }, [contactState ])
```

Or you need to reset the error value & message on post request

```
 case CONTACT_POST:
      return {
        ...state, error:false, messages:""
      }
```

Comment: Second suggestion is saved me! Thanks!